# Exception executing consequence for rule (Drools, Guvnor, JBPM5)

Tags: drools, jbpm, guvnor

am new to BPM, using JBPM5.4 installer.

below is the my drl source code taken from Guvnor..
when firing the rules am getting the error.

```
rule "TestRule"
        dialect "java"
        when
            exists (Person( name == "estaban" ))
        then
            Person.setName( "ESTABAN" );
    end
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception executing consequence for rule "TestRule" in com.tcs: java.lang.NullPointerExceptio
n
    at org.drools.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.j
ava:39)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1297)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:1221)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1456)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:710)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:674)
    at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:230)
    at com.sample.ProcessMain.main(ProcessMain.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tcs.Rule_TestRule_063717b0a0b841d3ae5b0d9fa14879f8.defaultConsequence(Rule_TestRule_063717b0a0b841d3ae5b0d9fa148
79f8.java:7)
    at com.tcs.Rule_TestRule_063717b0a0b841d3ae5b0d9fa14879f8DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.Rule_TestRule_063717b0a0b841d3ae5b0d9fa14879f8DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.drools.common.DefaultAgenda.fireActivation(DefaultAgenda.java:1287)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the fact found in the left-hand-side to a variable. Re-write like so:

```
rule "TestRule"
    dialect "java"
when
    $person: Person( name == "estaban" )
then
    $person.setName( "ESTABAN" );
    update( $person );
end
```

To do this in Guvnor, when you add/modify the constraint, you will see a "Modify constraints for Person" dialog box. You need to type a variable name such as "$person" in the "Variable name" text box.

This will cause it to change the generated DRL from :

```
Person( name == "estaban" )
```

to:

```
$person: Person( name == "estaban" )
```

Once you have bound the variable on the LHS then you need to modify the RHS. Select the option "Modify a field of an existing fact". You then need to select your variable name from the list provided and provide the details of which property to modify.

Comment: Alternatively you can modify the fact, which is supposed to be more efficient. `modify( $person ){ setName( "ESTABAN" ) };`

Comment: I have formed the rule through guided rule. Hence code change is not possible for me

Comment: If you're doing this through the guided rule editor in Guvnor then you need to bind the Person on the LHS to a variable ($person) and then modify that bound variable on the RHS.